# Compare 2 sheets and add subtraction result in comment

Tags: excel, vba

I need code which compares 2 sheets and writes the result of subtraction in a comment.

I have the code to compare 2 columns but I don't know how to remodel this code to work with whole sheets.

Current code:

```
Sub D_ValueToComment()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Dim rCell As Range
    For Each rCell In Selection
        With rCell
            If .HasFormula Then
                .Comment.Delete
                Else: .AddComment
                .Comment.Text Text:=CStr("Wynik: " & rCell.Value - (rCell.Offset(0, 1).Value))
            End If
        End With
    Next
    Set rCell = Nothing 
End Sub
```

[image: Photo of existing code]

[image: Sheets I need macros for]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the follwing function
with 2 loops:

1. "ro" is the row number
2. "co" is the columns number

ro is between 3 and 12 and co is between 3 nd 14: you can change that as per your sheet

```
Sub comments()
'On Error Resume Next
For ro = 3 To 12
For co = 3 To 14
    s1 = Sheets(2).Cells(ro, co)
    s2 = Sheets(3).Cells(ro, co)
    Set Rng = Sheets(2).Cells(ro, co)
    Rng.ClearComments
    Rng.AddComment
    Rng.Comment.Text Text:="Wynik: " & s2 - s1
Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This will error if `Sheets(2)` is not the active sheet.   Qualify the `Cells` with `Sheets(2)` too (or bwtter, use a with block).  And anyway `Set Rng = Sheets(2).Range(Cells(ro, co), Cells(ro, co))` is better written as `Set Rng = Sheets(2).Cells(ro, co)`

Comment: Changed to Set Rng = Sheets(2).Cells(ro, co), thank you!

Comment: Thaks a lot, your answear almost fully solved my problem.
I have 1 more issue with this.
I use sheets with different ammount of projects in column B. So Is it possible to autoscale ammount of rows? I used this code: `Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select` Maybe designate ammount of rows by selecting active cell as B3 and scanning down by `.End(xlDown))` and selecting offset to 1 to right. I just need it to be fully automatic and compatible with several numbers of projects.

Comment: You can use instaead of a loop "for", a loop "while" and check if the cell is not empty